# Use of joinTransaction in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, persistence

The following code is from `JPA` specs. I could not understand why `em.joinTransaction()` is required in `createLineItem(int quantity)`.

Can anyone provide an apt explanation?

```
@Stateful
public class ShoppingCartImpl implements ShoppingCart {

   @PersistenceUnit
   private EntityManagerFactory emf;
   private EntityManager em;
   private Order order;
   private Product product;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
      em = emf.createEntityManager();
   }

   public void initOrder(Long id) {
      order = em.find(Order.class, id);
   }

   public void initProduct(String name) {
      product = (Product) em
            .createQuery("select p from Product p where p.name = :name")
            .setParameter("name", name).getSingleResult();
   }

   public LineItem createLineItem(int quantity) {
      em.joinTransaction();
      LineItem li = new LineItem(order, product, quantity);
      order.getLineItems().add(li);
      em.persist(li);
      return li;
   }

   @Remove
   public void destroy() {
      em.close();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, a few words of theory...

An *application-managed entity manager* participates in a JTA transaction in one of two ways.

1. If the persistence context is created inside the transaction, the persistence provider will automatically synchronize the persistence context with the transaction.
2. If the persistence context was created earlier (outside of a transaction or in a transaction that has since ended), the persistence context can be manually synchronized with the transaction by calling `joinTransaction()` on the `EntityManager` interface. Once synchronized, the persistence context will automatically be flushed when the transaction commits.

After reading the above definition a few questions may arise:

- how do we know that `ShoppingCartImpl` participates in JTA transaction ?
  Because the class has been annotated with `@Stateful` (or `@Stateless`) annotation so the intention is to execute the class within Java EE environment which by default uses JTA transactions. A class doesn't need such annotation, if it will be executed in Java SE environment.
- how do we know *application-managed entity manager* is used in this particular case?
  Because we are using `@PersistenceUnit` annotation to inject `EntityManagerFactory` and then manually creating and destroying `EntityManager`. By doing this we are telling Java EE container that we don't want our transaction to be automatically managed (like in case of *transaction-scoped entity manager* or *extended entity manager* types).
- why `em.joinTransaction()` is required in `createLineItem` method?
  By calling `em.joinTransaction()` we notify the *application-managed persistence context* that it should synchronize itself with the current JTA transaction. Without such call the changes to `Order` would not be flushed to the underlying database when the transaction commits (at the end of `createLineItem` method). 
  NOTE: since `EntityManagerFactory` instances are thread-safe and `EntityManager` instances are not, an application must not call `em.joinTransaction()` on the same entity manager in multiple concurrent transactions.

Comment: please explain **an application must not call em.joinTransaction() on the same entity manager in multiple concurrent transactions** a little briefly like what happens with an scenario.