# Joining a transaction in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, ejb

I'm migrating the code from EJB to Spring-Hibernate. How do I join the transaction and rollback if failure occurs? 
Below is the code in EJB :

```
entityManager.joinTransaction();
entityManager.persist(xyz);
entityManager.flush();
```

UPDATE 1: 
How do we join two transactions happening on different databases? 
There are 2 transactions which needs to performed atomically. If the second transaction fails, 1st transaction must be rollbacked. How to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `entityManager.joinTransaction();` is to notify the persistence context to synchronize itself with the current transaction ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24450391/1910582))

Since the code is being migrated to the Spring consider leveraging the out-of-box transaction abstraction available via [`@Transactional`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html). This  will make the call to `joinTransaction()` redundant and the rollback / commit will be taken care by Spring.

**Note** - Ensure that the [transaction settings](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings) are chosen appropriately so as to be inline with current implementation.