# Java transactions don't work when multiple entity managers are used

Tags: java, postgresql, wildfly, jta, distributed-transactions

I have been working a couple of weeks on a requirement that requires modifing  some methods that are using transactions, the code between the transaccion can read/update/delete/etc elements in the database(PostgreSQL) through the application. At this moment, the application is using a peristence unit (pointing to a wildfly datasource) and an entity manager to access the database:

For example:

```
@PersistenceContext( unitName="name", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION )
protected EntityManager em;

 public String updateReadRead()
{
    try
    {
        TransactionUtil.begin( this.utx );

        Query nativeQuery = this.em.createNativeQuery("update schema.company_info set service_manager_phone_ext = '1004';");
        int i = nativeQuery.executeUpdate();

        this.searchCriteriaApplication.trimVo();
        this.searchCriteriaCustomer.trimVo();
        this.searchResults = this.applicationSearchService.searchApplications( this.searchCriteriaApplication, this.searchCriteriaCustomer, this.em, false, true );

        this.showAccountsForCustomer = false;

        this.applicationSearchService.searchApplications( this.searchCriteriaApplication, this.searchCriteriaCustomer, this.em, false, true );
        TransactionUtil.commit(this.utx);
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {

    }
    return null;
}
```

But now, we want to use two entity managers,one in charge of the write operations (pointing to a transaccional Data Base) and the other one for read operations (pointing to a replica Data Base (ReadOnly DataBase)), for example:

```
@PersistenceContext( unitName="readonly", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION )
protected EntityManager readOnlyEM;

@PersistenceContext( unitName="readwrite", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION )
protected EntityManager readWriteEM;


 public String updateReadRead()
{
    try
    {
        TransactionUtil.begin( this.utx );

        Query nativeQuery = this.readWriteEM.createNativeQuery("update schema.company_info set service_manager_phone_ext = '1004';");
        int i = nativeQuery.executeUpdate();

        this.searchCriteriaApplication.trimVo();
        this.searchCriteriaCustomer.trimVo();
        this.searchResults = this.applicationSearchService.searchApplications( this.searchCriteriaApplication, this.searchCriteriaCustomer, this.readOnlyEM, false, true );

        this.showAccountsForCustomer = false;

        this.applicationSearchService.searchApplications( this.searchCriteriaApplication, this.searchCriteriaCustomer, this.readOnlyEM, false, true );

        TransactionUtil.commit(this.utx);
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {

    }
    return null;
}
```

I have tried two approaches:

1. Create a new entityManager pointing to the readonly database. It fails when we use the readonly entityManager and then, change to the write entityManager or vice versa (All ot this in the same transaction).

If we use two transactions, one for read operatios and the other one for write operations, it works.

(Please check error stacktrace below):

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:995)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:920)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.remove(SessionImpl.java:3341)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.remove(AbstractEntityManager.java:655)
    at com.snap.web.bean.SmartEntityManager.remove(SmartEntityManager.java:68)
    at com.snap.event.EventService.delete(EventService.java:221)
    at com.snap.accountmanager.AccountManagerService.deletePriorityNote(AccountManagerService.java:3877)
    at com.snap.api.AccountManagementResource.deletePriorityNote_aroundBody38(AccountManagementResource.java:1878)
    at com.snap.api.AccountManagementResource$AjcClosure39.run(AccountManagementResource.java:1)
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
    at com.snap.common.log.MethodLogger.around(MethodLogger.java:62)
    at com.snap.api.AccountManagementResource.deletePriorityNote(AccountManagementResource.java:1863)
    at com.snap.api.AccountManagementResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deletePriorityNote(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:162)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:201)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at
```

2. Use distributed transactions. I configured two new XA Data Sources and two new pesistence units associated to those datasources. I changed the entityManagers to point those new persistence units but the transaction fails when it tries to commit. I already set the max_prepared_transactions with the same value as maxSession property in both databases as the documentation suggests.

See stacktrace below:

```
javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1208)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:89)
    at org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction.commit(ServerVMClientUserTransaction.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:433)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.CallableMethodHandler.invoke(CallableMethodHandler.java:42)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weldx.transaction.UserTransaction$112420245$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.commit(Unknown Source)
    at com.snap.common.utils.TransactionUtil.commit(TransactionUtil.java:71)
    at com.snap.web.bean.application.SearchApplicationTransactionTests.smart_aroundBody4(SearchApplicationTransactionTests.java:339)
    at com.snap.web.bean.application.SearchApplicationTransactionTests$AjcClosure5.run(SearchApplicationTransactionTests.java:1)
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
    at com.snap.common.log.MethodLogger.around(MethodLogger.java:62)
    at com.snap.web.bean.application.SearchApplicationTransactionTests.smart(SearchApplicationTransactionTests.java:287)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:162)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:201)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: org.postgresql.xa.PGXAException: Error preparing transaction
            at org.postgresql.xa.PGXAConnection.prepare(PGXAConnection.java:323)
            at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.prepare(XAManagedConnection.java:330)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord.topLevelPrepare(XAResourceRecord.java:218)
            at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doPrepare(BasicAction.java:2662)
            at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doPrepare(BasicAction.java:2612)
            at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.prepare(BasicAction.java:2155)
            at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.End(BasicAction.java:1501)
            at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:96)
            at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1200)
            ... 97 more
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot execute PREPARE TRANSACTION during recovery
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2412)
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2125)
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:297)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:301)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:287)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:264)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:244)
            at org.postgresql.xa.PGXAConnection.prepare(PGXAConnection.java:315)
            ... 106 more
    Suppressed: org.postgresql.xa.PGXAException: Error rolling back prepared transaction
            at org.postgresql.xa.PGXAConnection.rollback(PGXAConnection.java:415)
            at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.rollback(XAManagedConnection.java:346)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord.topLevelAbort(XAResourceRecord.java:369)
            at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doAbort(BasicAction.java:3017)
            at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doAbort(BasicAction.java:2996)
            at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.phase2Abort(BasicAction.java:1979)
            at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.End(BasicAction.java:1517)
            at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:96)
            at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1200)
            ... 97 more
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot execute ROLLBACK PREPARED during recovery
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2412)
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2125)
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:297)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:301)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:287)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:264)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:244)
            at org.postgresql.xa.PGXAConnection.rollback(PGXAConnection.java:405)
            ... 106 more
```

Is any of these approches correct? in order to continue testing or is there a better solution to achieve the requeriment?

I will appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to consider using a [ChainedTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/transaction/ChainedTransactionManager.html)

Comment: As for your 1-st approach. Check the first part of the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24450391/8513835)  You can try experimenting with manual calls of joinTransaction() right before first use on both your readonly and readwrite entity managers inside particular transaction.

Comment: We need to see the rest of the stack trace from the 1st approach to find out why it results in `Unable to acquire JDBC Connection`. In the second approach, what do you mean by "wildfly distributed Data Sources"? Did you set up two XA data sources?

Comment: Hi @Steve, yes, i set up two XA data sources.